# NSScrollView background image in Lion

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, nsview, nsscrollview

I'm working on a Mac application with an `NSScrollView`, and I want the `NSScrollView` to have a custom background image. I used this code in the custom documentView `NSView` subclass:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    [[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"wood.jpg"]] set];
    NSRectFill(rect);
}
```

That displays a pattern image as a background for the documentView.

But now in Mac OS X Lion, the `NSScrollView` bounces when scrolling further than possible, showing ugly white space. How can I make the white space also being covered by the background image?

Comment: Hi! Which class did you subclass to override this method? How do you send the image on the back? ps. Is your background sliding correct and anchored to the top ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of overriding `drawRect:`, use the scroll view's `setBackgroundColor:` method, passing the NSColor you created with the pattern image.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me, because the background doesn't scroll then. It's fixed to the ScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

You should subclass use NSScrollView setBackgroundColor, but then you should subclass NSClipView like this to pin the texture origin to the top:

```
@implementation MYClipView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
  if (self.drawsBackground)
  {
    NSGraphicsContext* theContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
    [theContext saveGraphicsState];

    float xOffset = NSMinX([self convertRect:[self frame] toView:nil]);
    float yOffset = NSMaxY([self convertRect:[self frame] toView:nil]);
    [theContext setPatternPhase:NSMakePoint(xOffset, yOffset)];
    NSColor* color = self.backgroundColor;
    [color set];
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
    [theContext restoreGraphicsState]; 
  }  
  // Note: We don't call [super drawRect:dirtyRect] because we don't need it to draw over our background. 
}

+ (void)replaceClipViewInScrollView:(NSScrollView*)scrollView 
{
  NSView* docView = [scrollView documentView]; //[[scrollView documentView] retain]; 
  MYClipView* newClipView = nil;
  newClipView = [[[self class] alloc] initWithFrame:[[scrollView contentView] frame]]; 
  [newClipView setBackgroundColor:[[scrollView contentView] backgroundColor]];
  [scrollView setContentView:(NSClipView*)newClipView]; [scrollView setDocumentView:docView];
//  [newClipView release]; 
//  [docView release]; 
}
@end
```

And call `+ (void)replaceClipViewInScrollView:(NSScrollView*)scrollView` with the NSScrollView instance.

Answer (score 0):

Put your drawRect code in an NSScrollView subclass. In IB, change the NSScrollView to use your custom subclass instead of NSScrollView. Also make sure to uncheck Draw Background in the scroll view's attributes inspector.